# Problema al leer lineas de un archivo con símbolo de grado AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python

Estimados, en mi proceso de cambio de IDL a Python, estoy con algunos problemas de lectura y conversion.

Leyendo archivos que tienen la siguiente estructura (unas 4000 lineas como las tres que siguen):

```
00:00 15:00:28 -53°08'09.2" -70°52'54.0" 23.0 1002.9 9.4 60.2 0.2773 23.2 9.5690 0.0095 0.0158 1.9 29.4
00:00 15:00:28 -53°08'09.2" -70°52'54.0" 23.0 1002.9 9.4 60.2 0.2773 23.2 9.5690 0.0095 0.0158 1.9 29.4
00:00 15:00:28 -53°08'09.2" -70°52'54.0" 23.0 1002.9 9.4 60.2 0.2773 23.2 9.5690 0.0095 0.0158 1.9 29.4
```

Me interesa cambiar los grados minutos y segundos a decimal, es decir `-53°08'09.2" = 53.1358888889`, el codigo que estoy intentando es:

```
path1 = '/Users/Documents/all2016_txt/allclean/cPA_160226.txt
degree_sym = u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'
regex = r'(-?)(\d+)'+ degree_sym + r"(\d+)'" + r'(\d+|\d+\.\d+)"'
converted_words = []
if os.path.exists(path1):
    with open(path1, 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors="surrogateescape") as f:
        for line1 in f:
            for word in line1.split():
                m = re.match(regex, word, flags=re.UNICODE)
                if m:
                    sign    = int(m.groups()[0]+'1')
                    degrees = float(m.groups()[1])
                    minutes = float(m.groups()[2])/60.0
                    seconds = float(m.groups()[3])/3600.0
                    result  = "{0:.5f}".format(sign*(degrees+minutes+seconds))
                    converted_words.append(result)
                else:
                    converted_words.append(word)
            answer = " ".join(converted_words)
            print(answer)`
```

Pero al hacer rodar el modulo me aparece el error:

> for word in mylist.split(): AttributeError: 'list' object has no
>   attribute 'split'

Agradezco la ayuda

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer mas acerca de este sitio.

Comment: Istari el error que comentas no se puede reproducir con ese código, para empezar en tu código no existe el objeto `mylist` y que es el causante del error al aplicar el método `split` de las cadenas a una lista. Pon siempre un ejemplo que reproduzca el error y coloca el error al completo, con toda la traza,  en Python los errores se suelen retornar de forma muy clarita. Añadir la versión de Python que usas también ayuda, aunque en este caso parece ser Python 3.x por como está construido el `with`.

Comment: Perdon hice tantos cambios que me perdi.... en realidad mylist.split() es line1.split()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como ya ha comentado toledano en su respuesta el código tiene algunos problemas derivados posiblemente de una mal copia al crear la pregunta. En cuanto al error en si, como te comenté no es reproducible en tu código de ejemplo. `split()` es un método propio de las cadenas (`str`) que no existe para las listas. Por lo que parece estas intentando aplicarlo a una lista y de ahí el error. El problema es que la lista que te marca el error llamada `mylist` no existe en tu código y `line1` que es donde usas `split` en tu código si que son cadenas resultado de iterar sobre `f` que es un objeto de tipo `TextIOWrapper`, por lo que no pueden retornar este error.

A la espera de ver si se aclara la pregunta voy a dejar otra versión para hacer lo mismo usando [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.sub). Este método sustituye cada coincidencia por una cadena dada, en este caso la cadena se la da la función `convertir` que toma como argumento cada coincidencia con el patrón y retorna los grados en decimal.

```
import os
import re

path1 = '/Users/Documents/all2016_txt/allclean/cPA_160226.txt'
degree_sym = u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'
patt = re.compile(r'(-?)(\d+)'+ degree_sym + r"(\d+)'" + r'(\d+|\d+\.\d+)"')

def convertir(matchobj):
    sign    = int(matchobj.groups()[0]+'1')
    degrees = float(matchobj.groups()[1])
    minutes = float(matchobj.groups()[2])/60.0
    seconds = float(matchobj.groups()[3])/3600.0
    return "{0:.5f}".format(sign*(degrees+minutes+seconds))

if os.path.exists(path1):
    with open(path1, 'r', errors="surrogateescape") as f:
        answer = [re.sub(patt,convertir ,line) for line in f]
        print(*answer, sep = '')
```

Lo que nos da usando tu ejemplo una salida:

```
00:00 15:00:28 -53.13589 -70.88167 23.0 1002.9 9.4 60.2 0.2773 23.2 9.5690 0.0095 0.0158 1.9 29.4
00:00 15:00:28 -53.13589 -70.88167 23.0 1002.9 9.4 60.2 0.2773 23.2 9.5690 0.0095 0.0158 1.9 29.4
00:00 15:00:28 -53.13589 -70.88167 23.0 1002.9 9.4 60.2 0.2773 23.2 9.5690 0.0095 0.0158 1.9 29.4
```

El código queda más corto y es más eficiente que usar ciclos y condicionales, aunque se pierde, tal vez, legibilidad.

`answer` es una lista con las lineas del archivo original con todos los angulos pasados a decimal.Esta lista la podemos imprimir como hago yo usarla para crear otro archivo de salida usando `writelines()` simplemente con algo como:

```
with open('salida.txt', 'w') as salida:
    salida.writelines(answer)
```

`answer` solo existe dentro del `with`, si se desea usar fuera basta con definirla antes del `with`.

El código es para Python 3.x, si se desea usar en Python 2.x la idea original es la misma, solo hay que modificar el `print` y `open`.

Comment: Prefiero esta versión. Me parece más legible usar funciones. El objeto `re` debería ser un argumento de la función y tendría más usos. De 10!

Comment: 14:52:22  -53\udca1\udcc608\'09.2"   -70\udca1\udcc652\'53.8"                     22.0          1003.0              10.0             56.4                   0.0238                                    21.4                         0.0824                               0.0001                          0.0001               0.0                 0.0\n', '                                -08:05

Comment: sigo con problemas, al parecer en mac todo es un poco mas complicado. Mala idea cambiar simultaneamente de Win a Mac y a la vez de IDL a Python. En pantalla la salida es: 14:52:24  -53\udcc2\udcb008\'09.2"   -70\udcc2\udcb052\'53.8"                     22.0          1003.0              10.2             56.8                   0.0225                                    21.4                         0.0310                               0.0000                          0.0001               0.0                 0.0\n', '  Podrias ayudarme porfa?

Comment: @Istari aparentemente son problemas de codificación, no debería importar mucho en principio el SO dada la naturaleza de Python (quitando algunas cosas concretas como el final de linea en archivos u librerias específicas). Lo que te aparece como \udcc son caracteres unicode. ¿Eso te lo muestra usando qué código?, ¿es el resultado de un print o de una escritura en un archivo? Da algo de más información o crea una nueva pregunta a ver si damos con lo que pasa. ¿Que versión de Python usas, 2.x o 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

Yo probé el código y necesita algunas modificaciones, tal vez por la forma en la que lo copiaste.

```
import re

path1 = './data.txt'
degree_sym = u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'
r = re.compile(r'(-?)(\d+)'+ degree_sym + r"(\d+)'" + r'(\d+|\d+\.\d+)"', flags=re.UNICODE)
converted_words = []

for l in open(path1).readlines():
    for w in l.split():
        m = r.match(w)
        if m:
            sign    = int(m.groups()[0]+'1')
            degrees = float(m.groups()[1])
            minutes = float(m.groups()[2])/60.0
            seconds = float(m.groups()[3])/3600.0
            result  = "{0:.5f}".format(sign*(degrees+minutes+seconds))
            converted_words.append(result)
        else:
            converted_words.append(w)
    converted_words.append('\n')
    answer = " ".join(converted_words)

print(answer)
```

Uso un objeto `re.compile()`  mas por costumbre que por las razones que expone la documentación, que dice que crear un objeto `re` hace más eficiente los procesos porque se reutiliza, en lugar de compilar y buscar en cada vuelta.

Uso `readlines()`, por la misma razón: por deformación profesional, aunque entiendo que el uso de generadores de este tipo es más eficiente en python.

El archivo `data.txt`  contiene las líneas de ejemplo. Esta es la salida:

```
00:00 15:00:28 -53.13589 -70.88167 23.0 1002.9 9.4 60.2 0.2773 23.2 9.5690 0.0095 0.0158 1.9 29.4 
 00:00 15:00:28 -53.13589 -70.88167 23.0 1002.9 9.4 60.2 0.2773 23.2 9.5690 0.0095 0.0158 1.9 29.4 
 00:00 15:00:28 -53.13589 -70.88167 23.0 1002.9 9.4 60.2 0.2773 23.2 9.5690 0.0095 0.0158 1.9 29.4
```